# Hyperlinks to enumeration numberings

Tags: indentation, enumerate

I have a list

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is the first post
\item This is the second post
\end{enumerated}
```

And I want to add hyperlinks to the numberings within a box.

The simplest approach can be using my own numbering (using a counter, or manually)

```
\boxed{ \href{www.google.com}{1} } This is the first post
\boxed{ \href{www.google.com}{2} } This is the first post
```

But with this structure, I lost the indentation that "enumerate" presents.
How can I preserve the indentation

[image]

Comment: With an `enumerate`d environment, you can assign `\label`s to individual items and cross-reference them elsewhere via `\ref` statements. And, if `hyperref` is loaded these cross-references will be made into hyperlink targets automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your problem right, this works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is the first post
\item[\boxed{\href{www.google.com}{2}}] This is the second post
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```